# Using XSD to validate multiple roots

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm working on this project where we are only allowed to use one XSD file to validate multiple XML files.

I have this one problem I can't seem to figure out nor can I find something similar that was asked before, my apologies if this is a duplicate question.

Say I have this one XML document call it `currencies.xml` that has the following XML inside it:

```
<index>
    <currency>USD</currency>
    <currency>EURO</currency>
</index>
```

which must contain at least 1 `<currency\>` element but can have as many as need be.
Now, say I have multiple other XML file's with the same name as the currency values inside `currencies.xml`, but for simplicity sake lets take only the USD currency's file `USD.xml` which contains the following:

```
<index>currency="USD">
    <country short="USA">United States of America</country>
</index>
```

This time its permissible to have 0 `<country\>` elements, and also as many as need be.

So inside my validation XSD file I have the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="root">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="currency" type="WithoutAttrib"/>
        <xs:element name="country" type="WithAttrib"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="currency" type="rootAttribute" />
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="WithAttrib">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="root">
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="country" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="stringElement">
                                <xs:attribute name="short" use="required"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="WithoutAttrib">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="root">
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="currency">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:maxLength value="30"></xs:maxLength>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="index" type="root"/>
```

The `stringElement` is defined as follows:

```
<xs:simpleType name="stringElement">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

So far this was the best solution I could come up with but it doesn't work as I need it to, could someone perhaps help me out by either providing a link to a similar question that I can use or perhaps give me some advice on how to get this working.

I'm also not entirely sure if the attribute should be declared inside the root, any advice regarding it would be appreciated as well.

In case you need more information about something specific, leave me a comment and I'll make an edit. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nothing in the XML to differentiate between the schema rules you require, so your XSD must be a superset of all the valid attributes and elements in `<index>`. Is the XML format fixed or can you change it?

The following does what you want, but as you have attributes in the `index` element, the `choice` can not group the attribute with the `country` element.

Its less than ideal.

[image]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <!--Created with Liquid Studio 2021 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
  <xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <xs:element name="index">
        <xs:complexType>
           <xs:choice>
              <xs:element name="currency" type="currencyType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              <xs:element name="country">
                 <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                       <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                          <xs:attribute name="short" type="currencyType" />
                       </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                 </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
           </xs:choice>
           <xs:attribute name="currency" type="currencyType" />
        </xs:complexType>
     </xs:element>
     <xs:simpleType name="currencyType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
           <xs:enumeration value="USD" />
           <xs:enumeration value="GBP" />
           <xs:enumeration value="EUR" />
        </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would there perhaps be someway where I can test whether or not the root has the attribute and based on that it would validate the structure accordingly? Eg. if the root has the attribute then it should contain `0..unbounded `country elements otherwise it should contain `1..unbounded` currency items

Comment: Its not possible in XSD 1.0 I think its possible in XSD 1.1, but is that an option? Is the XML format fixed?

Comment: okay I understand, it was something I should have implemented in some way, but this works good enough. Thank you for you answer and reply!